# Filter by multiple hstore keys in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activeadmin, ransack

I'm trying to add a custom filter field for an `hstore` field.

In activeadmin: `filter :by_title, label: 'Title', as: :string`

In model :

```
ransacker :by_title do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', 
  parent.table[:title_translations], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('en'))
end
```

This code is searching creating the correct query depending on the activeadmin selection (contains, equals, starts_with or ends_with)

I use the hstore to store title for multiple locales. I'd like to search in ALL locale. Not only `en`, but `fr`, `es`, `ru`, etc

Comment: Have you looked through the [wiki articles on filters](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki#index-pages-filters-and-scopes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using a custom scope like so:

```
# Ransackable Scopes
def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
  [:by_title]
end

# My scopes
scope :by_title, ->(search_term) { by_field(search_term, :title) }

scope :by_field, lambda { |search_term, field|
  where("#{field}_translations -> :key ILIKE :value", key: :en, value: "%#{search_term}%")
    .or(where("#{field}_translations -> :key ILIKE :value", key: :fr, value: "%#{search_term}%"))
    .or(where("#{field}_translations -> :key ILIKE :value", key: :de, value: "%#{search_term}%"))
}
```

It doesn't exactly answer the question, but was a solution that worked for me needs.

Comment: Thanks I was searching for solution to add filters on jsonb data in my active Admin and this saved my day